# Loop over a number of files to carry out filtering

Tags: loops, awk

I have a list of files (15 in total) with different filenames all in the same format except the 4th world highlighted in bold.

```
Late_Tox_GWAS.**TelangiectasiaG1**_resid.glm.linear
Late_Tox_GWAS.**AtrophyG1**_resid.glm.linear
Late_Tox_GWAS.**AtrophyG2**_resid.glm.linear
Late_Tox_GWAS.**IndurationG1**_resid.glm.linear
```

etc...

All of these files are located in /scrat/genome/hj86/Late_Tox_GWAS/*_resid.glm.linear

All of these files have the same number of columns with same column names. I want to filter all of  these  files on column 7 for 'ADD'. I have ran this sample command to filter on  column  7 so that this  occurs for every file which should then save into separate  corresponding files e.g. the  next one would be AtrophyG1_resid_ADD and the next one would be AtrophyG2_resid_ADD etc...

I am new to loops and didn't know how to code so that each individual toxicity is read in and didn't know how to specify the unique bit of the file name so that each file gets processed and the results are saved to the corresponding unique file name. I would be grateful for any help.

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N Late_Tox_regression_ADD
#PBS -l walltime=01:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -l vmem=16gb
#PBS -m bea
#PBS -M my email address
set -x


for fname in /scrat/genome/hj86/Late_Tox_GWAS/*_resid.glm.linear

do
    tox="${fname#*.}"                      
    tox="${tox%%_*}"                         

    awk 'NR==1 || $7 == "ADD"{print}' "${fname}" > "${tox}_resid_ADD"

done
```

I dont get any output just a file that says:

```
+ for fname in '/scratch/genomeqol/hkj7/Late_Tox_GWAS/*_resid.glm.linear'
+ tox=AtrophyG1_resid.glm.linear
+ tox=AtrophyG1
+ awk 'NR==1 || $7 == "ADD"{print}' /scratch/genomeqol/hkj7/Late_Tox_GWAS/Late_Tox_GWAS.AtrophyG1_resid.glm.linear
+ for fname in '/scratch/genomeqol/hkj7/Late_Tox_GWAS/*_resid.glm.linear'
+ tox=AtrophyG2_resid.glm.linear
+ tox=AtrophyG2
+ awk 'NR==1 || $7 == "ADD"{print}' /scratch/genomeqol/hkj7/Late_Tox_GWAS/Late_Tox_GWAS.AtrophyG2_resid.glm.linear
+ for fname in '/scratch/genomeqol/hkj7/Late_Tox_GWAS/*_resid.glm.linear'
+ tox=IndurationG1_resid.glm.linear
+ tox=IndurationG1
+ awk 'NR==1 || $7 == "ADD"{print}' /scratch/genomeqol/hkj7/Late_Tox_GWAS/Late_Tox_GWAS.IndurationG1_resid.glm.linear
+ for fname in '/scratch/genomeqol/hkj7/Late_Tox_GWAS/*_resid.glm.linear'
+ tox=Induration_G2_resid.glm.linear
+ tox=Induration
+ awk 'NR==1 || $7 == "ADD"{print}' /scratch/genomeqol/hkj7/Late_Tox_GWAS/Late_Tox_GWAS.Induration_G2_resid.glm.linear
```

Comment: updated the latest `awk` edit to fix a typo in the name of the file `awk` is writing to; while the code was not writing to the file you expected I'm guessing if you look in the current directory you'll find a file named `{tox}_resid_ADD` (that's a result of the typo/mistake in my original answer)

Comment: also, the lines of output starting with `+ ...`, these are the result of running `set -x` (ie, enable debug mode), and those lines are showing the desired strings are being parsed out as expected (eg, `tox=AtrophyG1` for the first file); removing the `set -x` will disable the printing of these `+ ...` lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit confused as to where the files are located and how many we're processing:

- `FILEPATH/${tox}/*.glm.linear*` would seem to indicate there's a separate sub-directory for each `${tox}` but possibly several files in said sub-directory
- `for entry in FILEPATH/${tox}/*.glm.linear*` would seem to imply there may be several files to process in this one directory (`FILEPATH/${tox}`) but `entry` is never referenced anywhere else in the code so ...
- we could end up processing the file named `Late_Tox_GWAS.{tox}_resid.glm.linear` multiple times (ie, once for each `entry=*.glm.linear*` file)

Assumptions:

- OP knows how to locate the list of files to be processed (for the sample code I'm going to use a `find` command as an example)
- all output is written to the 'current' directory (otherwise the sample code can be modified to write to the correct directory)

One idea using parameter substitutions to pull the desired string from the file name, then using this to run OP's `awk` script:

```
while read -r fname
do
    tox="${fname#*.}"                        # strip off all characters from the front of the string up to and including the first "."
    tox="${tox%%_*}"                         # strip off all characters from the first "_" to the end of the string

    awk 'NR==1 || $7 == "ADD"{print}' "${fname}" > "${tox}_resid_ADD"

done < <(find FILEPATH -name "*.glm.linear" -type f)
```

In my environment where I replaced `FILEPATH` with `dir3/sdir2` (the location of 4x `*.glm.linear` files) this code executed the following commands:

```
awk NR==1 || $7 == "ADD"{print} dir3/sdir2/Late_Tox_GWAS.AtrophyG1_resid.glm.linear > AtrophyG1_resid_ADD
awk NR==1 || $7 == "ADD"{print} dir3/sdir2/Late_Tox_GWAS.AtrophyG2_resid.glm.linear > AtrophyG2_resid_ADD
awk NR==1 || $7 == "ADD"{print} dir3/sdir2/Late_Tox_GWAS.IndurationG1_resid.glm.linear > IndurationG1_resid_ADD
awk NR==1 || $7 == "ADD"{print} dir3/sdir2/Late_Tox_GWAS.TelangiectasiaG1_resid.glm.linear > TelangiectasiaG1_resid_AD
```

Resulting in the following files being created in my current directory:

```
$ ls -1 *resid*ADD
AtrophyG1_resid_ADD
AtrophyG2_resid_ADD
IndurationG1_resid_ADD
TelangiectasiaG1_resid_ADD
```

Comment: Thank you, but all the files are located in the same directory . (They are all together not in different directories). Maybe I don't need entry. Sorry I was not sure what entry meant.

Comment: yeah, I'm confused by your example as to where the files reside; regardless, just update the `find` command to look in the correct location; alternatively replace `while read -r fname` and `done < <(find ...)` with `for fname in directory/where/files/live/*glm.linear` and `done`, respectively; the key issue is to make sure `fname` contains the name of the file, from there the parameter substitutions should strip out the desired string (assuming all files have the same format as displayed in your question)

Comment: So for my understanding is tox="${fname#*.}"  getting rid of Late_Tox_GWAS and the tox="${tox%%_*} getting rid of  _resid.glm.linear

Comment: I am not getting any output when running this. I have swapped the while read  etc.. and righting the  file path to my files  and getting rid of find FILEPATH

Comment: you can try adding `set -x` (to enable debug mode) before the `while`, run the script and review the output to see if that gives you an idea on where the issue lies; alternatively you may need to update the question with more details that would allow use to mimic your environment; at this point without any details I can't tell if your loop is not finding any files to process or if your loop is processing files but generating wrong results and/or empty files ... ?

Comment: Thanks I  have done that. I get the above error code (see original question that has been edited). Also, I was wondering when I have the tox= and then tox= again, isn't that overwriting the original tox?

Comment: yes, `tox= / tox=` will overwrite the first `tox` but in this code the first `tox` is just an intermediate step; and I just noticed a big typo/mistake on my part; I've updated the answer, replacing `{tox}_resid_ADD` with `"${tox}_resid_ADD"` ... not sure where my head was when I typed up the original answer as I had the correct code in my environment, apologies!

Comment: Sorry I figured it out! All I needed was the file path at  the top cd /what/directory!

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help.